# Remove "api" prefix from Web API url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got an API controller

```
public class MyController : ApiController { ... }
```

By default it is mapped to URL `mysite/api/My/Method`, and I'd like it to have URL without "api" prefix: `mysite/My/Method`

Setting controller attribute `[RoutePrefix("")]` didn't help me.

Are there any other ways to achieve that?

Comment: `api` word is configured in the Register method of WebApiConfig static class.

Comment: Are you using attribute routing or convention-based routing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The default Registration is usually found in `WebApiConfig` and tends to look like this

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

You need to edit the `routeTemplate` in the convention-based setup.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Do note that if this project is shared with MVC that the reason for the `api` prefix was to avoid route conflicts between the two frameworks. If Web API is the only thing being used then there should be no issue.

Comment: I would just mention that the default AccountController has `[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]`, so in order for this to work for this controller as well, you need to remove `api/` from here as well.